# Can't install 12.04 server under Intel Pentium M

Tags: intel, cpu

I recently decided to upgrade ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04. My old MV Mobeus was already dual-booting the desktop and server versions of Ubuntu from the GRUB boot loader.

I managed to upgrade the desktop version from 10.04 to 12.04 easily, and without any problems, but since I'd already hashed up my server installation, I decided to reinstall the server.

I was soon told by the installer that my processor didn't have 'pae' (physical address extension), but leaves me to question whether or not there are significant kernel differences between desktop and server.

By the way, the processor is the Intel Pentium M 1.6Ghz, with Intel SpeedStep Technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 32bit ships with the PAE kernel by default, both the desktop and server editions, apparently. The generic 32bit kernel is still in the repositories, but if the CPU doesn't have PAE support, you can't use the regular installation image. That said, the [Minimal ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) should work.

Comment: The Processor has PAE support, but the minimal ISO worked! Thanks for replying so soon, and generally, thanks for being awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Some Pentium M 1.6 GHz CPUs do have PAE support (Dothan, the newer ones), [but the older ones (Banias) don't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_M#Banias).