# Can I Install Ubuntu on a older laptop with a intel pentium processor (which doesn't have pae)?

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 13.04, pae

I currently have Ubuntu 11.10, and I finally decided to upgrade. So I downloaded the .iso file from the site (Ubuntu 13.04, 32 bit), and put it on a 2gb thumb drive. I booted from the thumb drive, and it gave the error message:

```
This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU:
pae

Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

I saw a post suggesting that I use Update Manager, but I don't want to end up downloading the update, then when its half way through the install process, my computer might crash, and then i would lose all my data etc (I don't know if that is a proper assumption, because I don't know much about Ubuntu)... Can I use the minimal CD talked about it https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD ? I don't want to mess anything up with a stupid mistake, so thanks for the help. (Btw, I have a dual boot with windows XP and Ubuntu 11.10, if that makes any difference). I also understand that this is similar to the question asked in [Can't install 12.04 server under Intel Pentium M](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140855/cant-install-12-04-server-under-intel-pentium-m) , but

my processor is: Intel® Pentium(R) M processor 1.10GHz

Comment: "loose all my data".  Sounds like an excellent time for creating a backup of all your data.

Comment: Haha, already done, I just don't want to have the hassle of restoring it all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04 do not support NON-PAE CPU's

PAE releases are available in 13.04 (and 12.10), but you could try [Fake-PAE](http://ossnotebook.blogspot.com/2013/04/install-ubuntu-1210-or-1304-on-non-pae.html).

> 13.04 32 bit ISO require your CPU to have Physical Address Extensions, or PAE. "PAE is provided by Intel Pentium Pro and above CPUs,
>   including all later Pentium-series processors (except most 400 MHz-bus
>   versions of the Pentium M)." - If you have a NON-PAE CPU and would
>   like to install Lubuntu 12.10, please see [this link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-1210-on-non-pae.html) or you can use
>   12.04 instead.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes/Beta1/Lubuntu)</sup>

---

Linked Question:

- [How can I install on a non-PAE CPU? (error "Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-12-04-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-p)

Comment: Basically, I can install 12.04, but nothing later than that. Did I understand correctly? And how could i use Fake-PAE?

Comment: Correct.  To use Fake-PAE, just click on the link in the answer.

Comment: I installed fake-PAE, now do i just have to use update manager?
(edit: Sorry, i didn't click on the link before asking... :P fail...)